# Drush alias - @alias status could not be found

Tags: 7, drush

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a drush alias following the excellent example posted [here](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php).

EXAMPLE:

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
   'root' => '/path/to/drupal',
   'uri' => 'dev.mydrupalsite.com',
 );
```

MINE:

```
<?php
$aliases['main'] = array(
    'root' => '/srv/www/mysite/public',
    'uri' => 'main.mysite.net',
  );
?>
```

According to the example the following two commands are equivalent:

```
 $ drush @dev status
 $ drush --root=/path/to/drupal --uri=dev.mydrupalsite.com status
```

And if I run:

```
$ drush --root=/srv/www/mysite/public --uri=main.mysite.net status
```

I get a full report. But if I run

```
 $ drush @main status
```

I get the error `@main status could not be found`.

The alias file has been discovered, running `drush status` in the drupal root shows it has been found. It's `~/.drush/mysite.net.alias.drushrc.php`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filename pattern `mysite.net.alias.drushrc.php` will only be parsed for aliases named @mysite.net.  Rename this file to `mysite.net.aliases.drushrc.php`, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have more than one alias? If so, I would recommend you rename the file as `<youralias>.aliases.drushrc.php` . Based on your example, this would give `main.aliases.drushrc.php` - It doesn't hurt to have only one alias in such file anyway so I would default to `aliases.drushrc.php` every time, just to be on the safe side.

Next, confirm that the site alias is returned when you type:

```
$ drush sa
```

If it's not, clear drush cache to reload all changes:

```
$ drush cc drush
```

If this still doesn't work, run the command with the `--debug` flag and please post the debug log here.